# Can not send post request in android using volley (BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for API)

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to send data to my api with post method using volley but constantly having a error:

E/Volley: [714] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://.....

I am doing the same with postman.. it is working using postman but not in android..

Here is my code.....

```
StringRequest  stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username",user_name);
                params.put("password",user_password);
                params.put("email",user_email);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (android-studio) just because you use that IDE: these tags should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and the [tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that.. I am new to it. Thanks for helping and letting me know about it.

Comment: No worries. Just tag and frame questions properly, it makes it quicker and easier for others to search it and answer it.

Comment: This response is caused by sending wrong parameters with the URL but you can also control content-type, response and request type.

Comment: I checked everything twice. But still it was not working but finally today i got solution. may be there was some error in my php script. i changed my script and it worked..